# Javascript regex replace if the matched string length is greater than limit specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript regex to add a html markup for all the urls found like:

```
 var exp = /(((|www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)]))/ig;

popupText =  popupText.replace(exp , "<font color='red'>"+"<b>$&</b>"+"</font>" );
```

Now the problem is i want to make sure that it will word if the url found length is greater than 20 characters

See **$&** gets the match string i need to add a filter/check to gets its length.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't use `<font>`. It's 2012.

Comment: @bazmegakapa actually i am not a web designer so dont know which are obsolete now.But thanks i will possbly enclose it in a div and then apply a class m i right? Can you also suggest some article that will help me in improving and the things which are obsolete

Comment: The [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#elements-1) spec would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functional form of replace:

```
  popupText =  popupText.replace(exp , function(match) {
       if (match.length > 20)
            return "<font color='red'>"+"<b>" + match etc
       else
            return match; // return the argument, that is, don't replace
  })
```